# Clicking on a link within Safari without opening it

Tags: safari

In a CMS, the right frame shows the page to be changed, and the left frame the editing page. I can double-click on a text-block in the right frame to open it in an editing area in the left frame. However, if I hit accidentally a link string, this opens the linked page (twice) additionally to copying the text into the edit area. I can prevent this behaviour in Firefox by keeping the <kbd>alt</kbd> key pressed while clicking on the link (in Linux and Windows).

What can I do in Safari/Mac to prevent opening links when clicking on them?

Comment: Would using Firefox on OS X be an option for you?

Comment: Wouldn't pressing control while clicking the link let you copy the URL? I'm not sure if I understand the problem or if the answer could be that simple.

Comment: @patrix: no, not at all

Comment: @bmike: I just like to be able to double-click into a text without opening a hyperlink, if I accidentally hit one. In Firefox, I can keep the Alt-button pressed while clicking to prevent this, is there an option for Safari on Mac too?

Comment: What happens if you press alt — rather called Option on Mac — in Safari ?

Comment: It downloads the linked file.